# Y to CbCr conversion

Tags: colors, rgb

Is there any way to convert Y component(luma) directly to Blue Chrominance and Red Chrominance without using RGB to YCbCr conversion.

It means Can I use use Y component only to predict its Cb and Cr component directly

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. Y′, Cr, and Cb are three separate components of a color; Y′ is not based on Cr and Cb, and vice versa. There are multiple colors (with different Cr and Cb) that have a given Y′ component, with the exception of black and white.

What you may be asking for is *image colorization*, that is, how to add color to a black-and-white image. There are many ways to do so. In particular, however, restoration of a black-and-white image's former colors is anything but trivial.

Comment: ok thanks,,I have checked the literature,it is having gray to other color space conversion but not YCbCr conversion.Can you provide some reference links having Y to CbCr conversion not to LAB color sapce or any other

Comment: Are you looking to restore the colors of black-and-white images?

Comment: yes,,,basically wanted to predict Cb and Cr from its Y counterpart using learning procedure opf deep neural networks

Comment: Something like the following may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/junyanz/interactive-deep-colorization